# Sigmoid vs Softmax CrossEntropy on Object Detection

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I am working on object detection using MobileNetv1+SSD. I'm having difficulties with picking the right loss function for the classification.

In the SSD paper by Liu, Wei, et al., authors used the softmax loss over the multiple classes confidence `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. However, I am getting much better results using the sigmoid loss from Tensorflow [pipeline](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config) `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`.

My questions are:

- What are the main difference between both loses for object detection?
- What could be the reason to have this disparity of results using different losses?

Comment: I am having the same problem, I  training ssd+mobilenet for multiple classes and the results are much better when I use sigmoid. At the end, did you keep sigmoid? did softmax work for you?

Comment: @user2651062 Softmax worked better for me. I used the `score_converter: SOFTMAX` and some more parameter tuning and it worked as intented. As sigmoid function leads to a multiple classes predictions and I didnt want that.

Comment: @Guilhem Thanks for answering back. Softmax seems to work better indeed, but one should make sure to put it in the score_converter as well (which I forgot in my early experimentations, and had no detections at all). What bugs me is that the l2 regularization loss keeps on increasing when I use a high learning rate. I don't know if it's normal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use softmax cross-entropy loss, if **only one** class can be "true". The ground truth for one example (e.g. one image) in your task could look like `[0,0,0,1,0,0]`. These 6 values could, for example, represent 6 distinct classes such as `['cat', 'dog', 'house', 'fish', 'shoe', 'boat']`.

The final output of your network will be a list of "probability" scores for each scalar in your output vector. The probabilities will sum up to 1, e.g. `[0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.55, 0.15]`.

You would use a sigmoid loss function, if the problem you are trying to solve involves the possibility of **multiple** values being "true", e.g. the ground truth could be `[0,1,0,1,0,0]`.